# Apache Common Mails: Exception: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I implement automatic email sender after selenium execution and it works for non proxy environment but it does not work at corporate proxy environment. Anyone know what wrong with it? What need to change?

Code:

```
// Create the email message
            MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
            email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
            email.setSmtpPort(587);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("peterapiit@gmail.com", "giqqpudmcjjmpbcc"));
            email.setFrom("peterapiit@gmail.com", "Nicholas Wong");
            email.addTo("kwong@who.int", "Nicholas Wong");
            email.addTo("gann@who.int", "Nicholas Gann");
            email.setBounceAddress("peterwkc30@gmail.com");
            email.setSubject("ePQS Automation Testing Report");
            email.setMsg("Please find the ePQS Automation Testing Report from attachment");
            email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
            email.setSSLCheckServerIdentity(true);  
            email.setDebug(true); 

            email.getMailSession().getProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            email.getMailSession().getProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            email.getMailSession().getProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            email.getMailSession().getProperties().setProperty("mail.https.proxy.host", "http://10.64.150.9");
            email.getMailSession().getProperties().setProperty("mail.https.proxy.port", "8080");
```

Our company proxy require authentication. I believe javax.mail does not support it. Any java mail that support proxy authentication? Apache James.

How to set the proxy properly? Any idea? A billion thanks for your help.

Error:

> DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.2 DEBUG: successfully loaded resource:
>   /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map DEBUG: getProvider() returning
>   javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
>   DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication DEBUG SMTP:
>   protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=kwong,
>   password= DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true DEBUG SMTP:
>   trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
>   [INFO ] 2019-01-10 09:45:18.237 [main]  - Exception: Sending the email
>   to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587

Answer (score 1):

In your property setting, you have to change "protocol" to the actual name of the protocol you're using, e.g., "smtp".

Comment: Are you mean "mail.https.proxy.host" or specify the transport protocol?

Comment: No one willing to help on my problems.

Comment: Like I said above, the transport protocol, e.g., "smtp", the protocol for which you want it to use the proxy server.  `mail.smtp.proxy.host`

Comment: I had change it but it still failed to send email behind proxy. Our corporate proxy require authentication.

Comment: Our firewall blocks the connection.

Comment: Did you set the `mail.smtp.proxy.user` and `mail.smtp.proxy.password` properties?